# template string not getting transpiled properly

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

```
const ROOT_URL = "http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts";
const API_KEY = "?key=PWEFBIUB";
const url = `$(ROOT_URL)/posts$(API_KEY)`
```

Is getting transpiled into:-

```
var ROOT_URL = "http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts";
var API_KEY = "?key=PWEFBIUB";
var url = '$(ROOT_URL)/posts$(API_KEY)';
```

Why this happening I dont know. But babel is not working properly. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

For [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Syntax), the expression should go inside Curly brackets. Therefore you should use `{}` instead of `()`, like this

```
const ROOT_URL = "http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts";
const API_KEY = "?key=PWEFBIUB";
const url = `${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`
```